# Get unique length of data available in a column with comma separated in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, split, oracle11g

Need to get the unique length of data available in a column with comma separated. Have tried below queries but getting error saying

`ORA-00936: missing expression 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"  *Cause:     *Action: Error at Line: 2 Column: 16`

Query used

```
SELECT LISTAGG(
           SELECT DISTINCT LENGTH(ColumnName)
           FROM TableName
           WHERE LENGTH(ColumnName) NOT BETWEEN 6 AND 10) AS AliasName, ','
           ) within group (order by ColumnName) 
FROM DUAL;
```

Below query error out saying

`ORA-30482: DISTINCT option not allowed for this function 30482. 00000 -  "DISTINCT option not allowed for this function" *Cause:     *Action: Error at Line: 1 Column: 8`

```
SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT LENGTH(ColumnName), ',')  within group (order by LENGTH(ColumnName))
FROM TableName
WHERE LENGTH(ColumnName) NOT BETWEEN 6 AND 10;
```

Please assist me for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below query provide the required result.

```
SELECT listagg(AliasName, ',') within group (order by AliasName) AS NewAliasName 
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT LENGTH(ColumnName) AS AliasName
    FROM TableName
    WHERE LENGTH(ColumnName) NOT BETWEEN 6 AND 10
    );
```

Will I am able get better query than this.

Answer (score -1):

I just wonder why you want to convert the values to a single string.  Why not return multiple rows:

```
SELECT LENGTH(ColumnName)
FROM TableName
WHERE LENGTH(ColumnName) NOT BETWEEN 6 AND 10;
GROUP BY LENGTH(ColumnName) ;
```

This would allow you to add an extra column that counts the number of rows with a particular length.

Comment: Need to get the values which is out of range. If the value is assigned to a variable then it can be passed and add an entry in the log file.